# Looping an Array in Puppet

Tags: arrays, loops, puppet

I am trying to manage a file in puppet which sits in 100 different directories. The file is identical in each directory.

## I have an Array of directory names like below:

```
$directories = [ 'dir1' , 'dir2' , 'dir3' , 'dir4' , 'dir5' ]
```

## And the full directory path here:

```
file { "/var/www/assets/${directories}":
ensure  =>   "directory",
owner   =>   "apache",
group   =>   "apache",
mode    =>   750,
}
```

## Below is the file in question:

```
file { "/var/www/assets/${directories}/.htaccess":
ensure  =>   present,
owner   =>   "apache",
group   =>   "apache",
mode    =>   644,
source  =>   "puppet:///modules/apache/.htaccess",
}
```

Now the problem at the moment is when puppet is ran it is looking at the file path and not iterating over the array, instead treating the array of directories as a single string like so:

```
"/var/www/assets/dir1dir2dir3dir4dir5/.htaccess"
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction which will allow me to loop over each directory, ensuring there is a .htaccess file present in every directory, and the .htaccess file is identical to the .htaccess file in my source =>

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running recent Puppet and have the future parser enabled, then you can do this like so:

```
each($directories) |$directory| {
  file { "/var/www/assets/${directory}/.htaccess":
    ensure  =>   'file',
    owner   =>   'apache',
    group   =>   'apache',
    mode    =>   0644,
    source  =>   'puppet:///modules/apache/.htaccess',
  }
}
```

If you are using older Puppet, or do not want to enable the (experimental) future parser, or are simply a fan of doing things the old school way, then you can do it like so:

```
$files = regsubst($directories, '.*', '/var/www/assets/\0/.htaccess')
file { $files:
  ensure  =>   'file',
  owner   =>   'apache',
  group   =>   'apache',
  mode    =>   0644,
  source  =>   'puppet:///modules/apache/.htaccess',
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a  swift response John,

Once i am back in work tomorrow i will test this and let you know the outcome!